# Databricks cannot connect to Azure Synapse Analytics: Unexpected version returned: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Tags: azure, jdbc, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to write some data to Azure Synapse Analytics from Databricks notebook with following code:

```py
write_to_synapse = (
  spark.readStream.format('delta').option('ignoreChanges',True).table('turbine_agg') # Read in Gold turbine readings from Delta as a stream
    .writeStream.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")                                     # Write to Synapse (SQL DW connector)
    .option("url",dbutils.secrets.get(<scope>, <secret>))                                # SQL Pool JDBC connection (with SQL Auth) string 
    .option("tempDir", SYNAPSE_PATH)                                                      # Temporary ADLS path to stage the data (with forwarded permissions)
    .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
    .option("dbTable", "turbine_agg")                                                # Table in Synapse to write to
    .option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_PATH+"synapse")                              # Checkpoint for resilient streaming
    .start()
)
```

Where secret is in JDBC connection string format:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<on-demand-sql-pool>.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=master;user=<user>;password=<password>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected version returned: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    Aug 17 2020 07:52:53 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Make sure your JDBC url includes a "database=<DataWareHouseName>" option and that
it points to a valid Azure Synapse SQL Analytics (Azure SQL Data Warehouse) name.
This connector cannot be used for interacting with any other systems (e.g. Azure
SQL Databases).
```

I have a database option included, and database master exists.

What is wrong and how I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you connecting to sql on demand? That driver is for a sql pool. Sql on demand is for querying a data lake, which is also what spark is for - so you are going in circles!

Comment: yes, apparently on-demand pool does not allow to connect from databricks but made only for querying storage data...